# Пробелы в BoxLayout устанавливаются некорректно

Tags: java, swing, gui

Конкретно они все сбиваются в кучу перед остальными элементами.
Код примерно такого вида:

```
    mainPanel = componentPack.Panel.getPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    mainPanel.add(mainLabel);
    mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));

    mainPanel.add(selectLabel);
    mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));

    mainPanel.add(namesList);
    mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));

    mainPanel.add(selectionButton);
    mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 10)));

    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
```

Результат на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Box.createVerticalStrut(10) дает такой же результат.
В чем может быть проблема?

ПС, знаю, что можно попытать счастья с другими Layout, но хотелось бы разобраться с этой.

Comment: Прошу прощения, был не прав в ответе. Попробовал воспроизвести проблему локально, всё отлично отработало по вашему коду. Возможно вы как-то особенно создаёте панель? Пробовали просто `new JPanel()` ?

Comment: Поэкспериментировав еще немного так и не смог найти комбинацию, которая давала хотя бы похожий эффект, если это возможно, хотелось бы увидеть реальный код, который создаёт это окно, а не "примерно такого вида".

Comment: @Vartlok прошу прощения, но вопрос оказался в невнимательности: код был разбросан по десятку файликов и де-факто все компоненты добавлялись дважды - что и дало такой странный результат...